# Cache Auto Generated Django Admin Routes

Tags: django, caching, redis, django-admin

I want to cache the sql queries result in Redis DB in the django admin.AdminSite autogenerated for registered admin.ModelAdmin's

I am able to cache a custom url using cache_page and add it to CustomAdminSite

I have installed Django debug toolbar to view cache requests.

The custom url is getting cached.

I am unable to cache other auto generated admin routes.

Would it be possible to cache auto generated admin routes too?